# DoCmd.BrowseTo can't seem to find the correct way to use it

Tags: vba, ms-access

So I've done some research on this but I can't seem to find out how to use it.
so i have a frmMain. It has 2-levels of navigation controls. 
"NavigationMain", and the subnavigation control is called "NavigationSub".
Lets say the buttons on the sub are called "NavBtn1", "NavBtn2", "NavBtn3", etc. 
Now here's what i need: 
I'm currently in "NavBtn1"  which is bound to form: "frmTotal". "frmTotal" is a continues form with textboxes. When I click on a certain textbox on that form, Access needs to take me to the form that is bound to "NavBtn2" (which is "frmDetail".

So to summarize: frmMain has a navigation selecter. I'm inside "NavBtn1" (frmTotal), and when I click on a textbox I browse to "NavBtn2" (frmDetail).

I have tried severel things with DoCmd.BrowseTo, but no luck.

Edit:

So to be more clear: frmMain has the navigation control. Each navigationcontrol shows a specific form. So "NavBtn1" shows "frmTotal", "NavBtn2" shows "frmDetail". Both "frmTotal" and "frmDetail" are subforms on "frmMain". I will add a picture to visualise what I'm seeing.

[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZM3s.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please get a bit more clearly to this: 
how you mean "navigate" to frmDetail? Is it a subform or a own form?

What i understand now is that you want to open a form when you click in a textbox: Add a click event for your textbox and add this code :

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmDetail",acNormal
```

Comment: I have edited my previous comment, and added an image.

Comment: so on click on textbox you want to navigate to the group 2 tab?

Comment: Yes. It should navigate to "Detail". (frmDetail is bound to that)

Comment: Me.YourTabControlname.Pages.Item(IndexNumber).SetFocus , you see the IndexNumber at the Properties of your Tab

Comment: I have tried "Me.NavigationSub.Pages.Item(1).SetFocus" but this doesn't work. Probably because the textbox im clicking it located inside the subform "frmTotal", and I'm using "me." but since the Navigation control is inside frmMain it can't find it.

So I've changed it to "Form_frmMain." instead of "Me." but now it gives and error about ".Pages"

Comment: if its a subform, use it like this: Forms("TheNameOfYourMainForm")!YourTabControlName.Pages.Item(1).SetFocus

Comment: I've changed it to "Form_frmMain." instead of "Me." but now it gives and error about ".Pages"

Comment: Whats the err message then?

Comment: Forms("TheNameOfYourMainForm")!YourTabControlName.Pages.Item‌​(1).SetFocus did you tried

Comment: "Can't find the method or data member"

Comment: i just tested it works fine at me, are the names correct? Try again with index 0 or 2

Comment: Are you sure you use a Tab Control ? I got the feeling you try to use the single tab, you got to use the tab control it self, click a bit above the tabs to get the whole tab control

Comment: No it's a navigation control.
I have created the main form this way:
Create -> at Forms, click Navigation -> Horizontal tabs, 2 levels

Comment: So whats the issue with Docmd.BrowseTo, can you please post your sample code

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to use it. I have looked up a lot of documentary but I can't seem to find the correct way to use it.